# how to define a json type to a model field from django models

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

Can anyone tell me how to define a json data type to a particular field in models.

I have tried this

```
from django.db import models
import jsonfield

class Test(models.Model):
    data = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

but when I say `python manage.py sqlall xyz`
its taking the data field as text

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "xyz_test" (
   "data" text NOT NULL
)
;
```

I still tried to insert json data into that field but its giving error as :

```
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(15)
```

someone please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, in the background [JSONField actually *is* a TextField](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield/blob/master/jsonfield/fields.py#L142), so that's not a problem, that's the expected behavior. However, the 15-chars limit is a tad weird - can you share the value you were trying to save?

Comment: @yuvi this is the value - {'name':'xyz', 'email':'xyz@gmail.com', 'phone':'0123456789'}

Comment: I just recreated your model and was able to save that exact value to a jsonfield. Are you sure it's the jsonfield causing that error and not some different field that has a 15 chars limit?

Comment: ya its for that text field, anyways can you please post the procedure that you followed or syntax.

Comment: I copied your exact code, and it worked (both when I passed the json as a python dictionary and as a JSON string). Please post your code that produces the error below

Comment: appologies.!! error was from other field. got it buddy.

Comment: +1 for you time and help.

Comment: Sure thing. Added a proper answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the background [JSONField actually is a TextField](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield/blob/master/jsonfield/fields.py#L154), so that output from sqlall is not a problem, that's the expected behavior.

Further, I recreated your model and it worked just fine, both when entering the value as a string and as a python dictionary, no character limitation whatsoever. So my best guess it that the issue is a completely unrelated field that *does* have a 15 chars limit.

Answer (score 4):

A JSONField data type has been added to Django for certain databases to improve handling of JSON. More info is available in this post: [Django 1.9 - JSONField in Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007109/django-1-9-jsonfield-in-models)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Test(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()
```

Comment: why are we importing `from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField` if at the end we have to use `models.JSONField()`?

Comment: "django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField is removed except for "
            "support in historical migrations."   Use django.db.models.JSONField instead.

Answer (score 0):

First install `django-jsonfield` pypi package:

```
pip install django-jsonfield
```

Then simply use it:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    custom_field = JSONField(
        default=dict
    )
```