# Django 1.9 - JSONField in Models

Tags: django

I'm trying to set up a models file in Django 1.9 using the new JSONField.  I have found examples using postgres but none with MySql.  In the examples with postgres they do a

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
```

How do I go about importing it for MySql? 
Thanks

Comment: I think JSONField might be a PostgreSQL-only field

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Django `JSONField` is Postgres only.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField

**UPDATE:**

There is support for **MYSQL** via 3rd party library `django-mysql`

Answer (score 48):

**UPDATE**: Django 3.1 now supports `JSONField` natively for multiple databases: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.1/#jsonfield-for-all-supported-database-backends

---

As stated in other answers, Django's native JSONField (as of 1.9 and 1.10) is for PostgreSQL.

Luckily, MySQL 5.7.8+ comes with a [native JSON datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). You can add it your Django project with the *[django-mysql](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql)* package and Django 1.8+

`pip install django-mysql`

```
from django.db import models
from django_mysql.models import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_json_field = JSONField()
```

Read more about the *django_mysql* JSONField [here](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html#jsonfield).

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: And what should a serializer for such a model look like?! I'm using `django-mysql` but cannot figure out how to construct a serializer. Would you please, give me a hint or something. I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: @Albert you shouldn't need a serializer. Django-MySQL will take anything `json.dumps` takes and will store it as JSON. I believe you'd only need a serializer if you wanted to take row in the database and return it as JSON (for example, in an API.) In that case, you should use something like django-rest-framework. See the docs for the JSONField here: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html

Answer (score 6):

```
# Install jsonfield package
pip install jsonfield

# Define my model
from django.db import models
import jsonfield

class MyModel(models.Model):
    the_json = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

More detail:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield

Comment: I'm trying to use the built-in feature that Django 1.9 provides.

Comment: @Rjay155 You can't without postgres. You're even importing it from `django.contrib.postgres`. Your only choice is to use a 3rd party module.

Comment: use "pip install django-jsonfield"

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is about Django 1.9, but JSONField can now be used with all supported database backends with the release of [Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#jsonfield-for-all-supported-database-backends).

Answer (score 2):

Try to save data of this model in postgres db on my local machine:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
 
from inputData.models import Input
 
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
 
class Results(models.Model):
 
    generator = models.OneToOneField(Input, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
 
    pvalues = JSONField()
```

views.py

```
def result(req, res_id):
    try:
        inp = Input.objects.get(pk = res_id)
        path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads\\' + str(res_id) + '\\t.txt')
        p_values = parse_res.main(path) 
        res = Results(generator = inp, pvalues = p_values)
        res.save(using = 'results')
    except Results.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(req, 'result.html', {'res': res})
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'results': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'results',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'USER': 'user',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '8000'

    }
    
}
```

Model Results (see models.py) uses JSONField, which have about 200 bytes of data
But at the line res.save(... of code views.py browser does response too long.

Whatäs wrong with JSON?
What problems can be on server besides cache?

Answer (score 1):

For today I'd recommend using [jsonfield2](https://github.com/rpkilby/jsonfield2) or waiting for [native JSON support](https://github.com/django/django/pull/11452) for all database backends in Django 3.

Answer (score 0):

Now in MySQL you can use default `models.JSONFile`, for more details read here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield

```
from django.db import models

class modelName(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     data = models.JSONField(default=dict, null=True)

     def __str__(self):
          return self.name
```