# Django change Model's field type from CharField to JSONField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using `Django 1.11` , I have been using `CharField` in Models, and dumping data in it using `json.dumps()`. I am using `mysql` database.

I want to change `CharField` to `JSONField`, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39281905/5130528) answer. Is there any way so that I can modify my field type without loosing the data?

Please note that the data in CharField is json dumped.

Comment: What happens when you just use a migration?

Comment: What do you mean by using a migration ?

Comment: What? Django has had migrations built in since 1.7. How have you created your database without using them?

Comment: Obviously I am using them, i didn't get what you want to know.

Comment: You asked how to change the type of a field. That is what migrations are for.

Comment: Is it safe to change to JSONField from CharField ? I won't loose any data for sure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166808/discussion-between-omkar-deshpande-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure it will be OK, but that's why I said to try it. Run it on development and see what happens.

Comment: I found this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49388419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely control the process write custom migration:

1) add new field of type JSONField null=True

2) copy data there using custom empty migration with
 with `RunPython` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython first

3) check everything was copied ok

4) remove old field

5) handle field rename eventually