# Django postgres make custom migration from CharField to JSONField

Tags: django, postgresql

I need to change this

```
data = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
```

to this

```
data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default={})
```

From what I understand, I have to write custom migration. Closest info I managed to find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274563/django-change-models-field-type-from-charfield-to-jsonfield?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I am completely clueless what to do with RunPython if that even correct thing to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a model like this

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and you need to change the `address` to a `JSONField`
So you have to define a `temporary field` as below

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField


class SampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    temp_address = JSONField(default={})
```

Then run the commands,
`python manage.py makemigrations app_name` and `python manage.py migrate app_name`
Then comes the role of [DATA MIGRATION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). What you have to do is that, run the command, `python manage.py makemigrations app_name --empty`
This willl create a `empty migration file` in your directory.Change that file into something like this
**0003_auto_20180320_1525.py** (migration file)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11 on 2018-03-20 15:25
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import json
from django.db import migrations
from sample.models import SampleModel


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    def forward_data_migration(apps, schema):
        for sample in SampleModel.objects.all():
            try:
                sample.temp_address = json.loads(sample.address)
                sample.save()
            except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print('Cannot convert {} object'.format(sample.pk))

    def revert_migration(apps, schema):
        pass

    dependencies = [
        ('sample', '0002_samplemodel_temp_address'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            code=forward_data_migration,
            reverse_code=revert_migration
        )
    ]
```

Migrate this change,then create another empty migration file as before, and write `RenameField` script as below
**0004_auto_20180320_1530.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11 on 2018-03-20 15:30
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('sample', '0003_auto_20180320_1525'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='samplemodel',
            old_name='address',
            new_name='temp_address'
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='samplemodel',
            old_name='temp_address',
            new_name='address'
        )

    ]
```

Migrate this too. That's it.

Comment: I think I got it. What is exactly 

`json.dumps(sample.address)`?

I used this, seems to be working.

`for obj in UserLog.objects.all():
        obj.data_json = obj.data
        obj.save()`

Comment: @vvAve here by json.loads we check "can TextField data can convert to json"

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in next steps:

1. Add new field with type [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) and run `makemigrations`:

   ```py
   data = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
   data_json = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default={})
   ```
2. Create [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) (using [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython))

   ```py
   import json

   from django.db import migrations

   def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
       MyModel = apps.get_model("myapp", "MyModel")

       for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
           try:
               obj.data_json = json.loads(obj.data)
               obj.save()
           except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
               print("Cannot convert {} object".format(obj.pk))


   class Migration(migrations.Migration):
       dependencies = []  # WRITE YOUR LAST MIGRATION HERE

       operations = [
           migrations.RunPython(forwards_func),
       ]
   ```
3. Remove old data field and run `makemigrations`:

   ```py
   data_json = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default={})
   ```
4. Rename the `JSONField` and run `makemigrations`:

   ```py
   data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default={})
   ```

P.S. You can use one migration for all this steps. I described all the steps for better understanding.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I must downvote it for the last sentence. It's a terribly bad advice, consider removing it altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806250/mix-data-and-schema-migrations-in-one-migrations-file-django