# Mix data and schema migrations in one migrations file (Django)?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I've heard the opinion that mix data migration and structure migrations is bad practice in Django. Even if you are specify atomic=False in your Migration class. But i could not find any information on this topic. Even my more expirience collegues could not answer this question.

So, is it bad to mix data and structure migrations? If so why? What exactly may happen if i do it?

Answer (score 3):

There is an actual reason for not mixing data and schema migrations in one migration, mentioned in the [entry for `RunPython` operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) in Django docs:

> On databases that do support DDL transactions (SQLite and PostgreSQL), `RunPython` operations do not have any transactions automatically added besides the transactions created for each migration. Thus, on PostgreSQL, for example, you should avoid combining schema changes and `RunPython` operations in the same migration or you may hit errors like `OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE "mytable" because it has pending trigger events`.

It should be also noted that for databases that do not support DDL transactions, it may be easier to fix the database after an unsuccessful migration attempt when data and schema migration operations are not mixed together, as data migration operations can be rolled back automatically in Django.

Answer (score 2):

In the past the best practice was to keep them separate. The second sentence in this section in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) says:

> Migrations that alter data are usually called “data migrations”;
>   they’re best written as separate migrations, sitting alongside your
>   schema migrations.

But doesn't list any reasons why. Since Django ~2.0 I've been allowing small data migrations to occur with schema migrations. However there have been times when the migration simply couldn't run with the schema migration. There are two main cases that I've run into.

1. The data migration takes a long time and shouldn't be a migration in the first place. The resolution was to simply run a script that did what the data migration would have, but in batches.
2. Attempting to add/update data, then creating an index. This forced me into splitting the migrations into two separate files. I don't remember the exact error, but it simply wouldn't migrate. This shouldn't cause problems for you unless there are non-atomic migrations running which would leave your DB in an unexpected state.

Comment: An exception in your data migration code will cause very sad times if you run a combined schema and data migration on MySQL which, from memory, has problems with transactions and schema changes.