# wrap multiple values in single JSON and store in model - Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, model

I want to store multiple inputs in single JSON field.

this is the order table , there is a "attribute_field" I want to store the attributes in this field
as JSON.

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField("Order ID", primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, verbose_name="Customer ID")
    prod_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, verbose_name="Product ID")
    quantity = models.ImageField('Product Quantity', max_length=10, default=500)
    attribute_value = models.CharField("Item Details JSON", max_length=2000, null=False)
    order_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0000.00)
```

**views.py**

```
def order(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer_id = request.user.user_id
        product_id = id
        try:
            size = request.POST['size']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            pass

        try:
            Colour = request.POST['Color']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            pass

        try:
            Paper_Choice = request.POST['PaperChoice']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            pass

    return render(request, 'user/order.html')
```

here I have not done form save method, but let me explain what I want to do.

I want to wrap SIZE, COLOR, PAPER CHOICE is single JSON and store it in attribut_values field in model but don't know how to do, can you please explain it to me.

Comment: See if this solves your problem - [JSONField in Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007109/django-1-9-jsonfield-in-models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Django version >= 3.1, you can use `JSONField`, otherwise use `TextField`.
Something like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Customer")
    prod = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Product")
    quantity = models.ImageField('Product Quantity', max_length=10, default=500)
    attribute_value = models.TextField("Item Details JSON")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
def order(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = request.user
        product_id = id
        try:
            size = request.POST['size']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            pass

        try:
            Colour = request.POST['Color']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            pass

        try:
            Paper_Choice = request.POST['PaperChoice']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            pass
        order = Order.objects.filter(user=customer, prod=product_id).first()
        value = dict(size=size, Colour=Colour, Paper_Choice=Paper_Choice)
        order.attribute_value = json.dumps(value)
        order.save()

    return render(request, 'user/order.html', {'order': order})
```

Comment: thanks it is working correctly but I forgot to mention one thing that if the user has selected the choice field only then the value should be added to the attribute value otherwise not so I think I have to fist create a dictionary and then use append method in try to store value in it if there is size selected or not, else thanks it is also working as I asked. For the question I asked it works.