# Json values into databse with Django

Tags: python, json, django

How I can insert `json` values that I am getting from `request.get("some url")` into database in **django**?

Comment: You could use [a JSON field](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field)

Comment: `request.get("some url").json()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 1.9 - JSONField in Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007109/django-1-9-jsonfield-in-models)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-json-field](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field) or insert `json` data in `TextField`.

For ex.

**models.py:**

```
import json

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    other_detail = models.TextField(default="{}")

    @property
    def other_detail_json(self):
        return json.loads(self.other_detail)
```

**views.py:**

```
# Insert JSON data
...
data = request.get("some url")
other_details = json.dumps(data)
MyModel.objects.create(other_detail = other_details,...)

#fetch JSON data
obj =  MyModel.objects.get(id = id)
other_detail = obj.other_detail_json
print(other_detail)
```